# How to count unique values in key-value pair (RDD)?

Tags: python, pyspark

I have the following output for a key-value pair for a RDD:

```
('William Hardin',
  (['Certified Refurbished Amazon Fire TV (Previous Generation - 1st)',
    'Certified Refurbished Amazon Fire TV (Previous Generation - 1st)',
    'Certified Refurbished Amazon Fire TV (Previous Generation - 1st)',
    'Certified Refurbished Amazon Fire TV (Previous Generation - 1st)',
    'Certified Refurbished Amazon Fire TV (Previous Generation - 1st)',
    'Amazon Fire TV',
    'Amazon Fire TV',
    'Fire HD 6 Tablet',
    'Fire HD 6 Tablet',
    'Fire HD 6 Tablet'],
   10))
```

However, I would like the output to be:

```
('William Hardin',
  (['Certified Refurbished Amazon Fire TV (Previous Generation - 1st)':5,
    'Amazon Fire TV':2,
    'Fire HD 6 Tablet':3],
   10))
```

Any help would be nice as I am new to Python and Pyspark.

Comment: Look at [`collections.Counter`.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

Comment: can u use spark2.4 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you have an RDD of such objects. So if the whole object you posted is one object in the RDD, I propose the following solution:

```
from collections import Counter

rdd1 = sc.parallelize([('William Hardin',
  (['Certified Refurbished Amazon Fire TV (Previous Generation - 1st)',
    'Certified Refurbished Amazon Fire TV (Previous Generation - 1st)',
    'Certified Refurbished Amazon Fire TV (Previous Generation - 1st)',
    'Certified Refurbished Amazon Fire TV (Previous Generation - 1st)',
    'Certified Refurbished Amazon Fire TV (Previous Generation - 1st)',
    'Amazon Fire TV',
    'Amazon Fire TV',
    'Fire HD 6 Tablet',
    'Fire HD 6 Tablet',
    'Fire HD 6 Tablet'],
   10))])

rdd2 = rdd1.map(lambda x: (x[0], (dict(Counter(x[1][0])), x[1][1])))
```

Output:

```
>>> rdd1.map(lambda x: (x[0], dict(Counter(x[1][0])), x[1][1])).take(1)
# [('William Hardin', ({'Certified Refurbished Amazon Fire TV (Previous Generation - 1st)': 5, 'Amazon Fire TV': 2, 'Fire HD 6 Tablet': 3}, 10))]
```